# How can I create a column target based on two different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-processing

I have the following DataFrame with the columns low_scarcity and high_scarcity (a value is either on high or low scarcity):

| id | low_scarcity | high_scarcity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | When I was five.. |  |
| 1 |  | I worked a lot... |
| 2 |  | I went to parties... |
| 3 | 1 week ago |  |
| 4 | 2 months ago |  |
| 5 |  | another story.. |

I want to create another column 'target' that when there's an entry in low_scarcity column, the value will be 0, and when there's an entry in high_scarcity column, the value will be 1. Just like this:

| id | low_scarcity | high_scarcity | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | When I was five.. |  | 0 |
| 1 |  | I worked a lot... | 1 |
| 2 |  | I went to parties... | 1 |
| 3 | 1 week ago |  | 0 |
| 4 | 2 months ago |  | 0 |
| 5 |  | another story.. | 1 |

I tried first replacing the entries with no value with 0 and then create a boolean condition, however I can't use `.replace('',0)` because the columns that are empty don't appear as empty values.

Comment: what if there are values in both or neither?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your dataframe is called `df` and that a value is either on on high or low scarcity, the following line of code does it

```
import numpy as np    
df['target'] = 1*np.array(df['high_scarcity']!="")
```

in which the `1*` performs an integer conversion of the boolean values.

If that is not the case, then a more complex approach should be taken

```
res = np.array(["" for i in range(df.shape[0])])
res[df['high_scarcity']!=""] = 1
res[df['low_scarcity']!=""] = 0
df['target'] = res
```

Comment: Any of them won't work :( it seems like the empty columns can't be accessed with empty values... When I try
`df_scarcity[df_scarcity['high_scarcity'] != '']`
I get the same output as the first dataframe in the question

Comment: I corrected the typos, sorry. They should work now

Comment: It worked! The thing was I had to use `df['target'] = 1*np.array(df['high_scarcity']!=" 
 ")`  (with two spaces) thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to stack overflow! please remember to mark your question as answered to repay my work https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow